# Made first git repo and it's duplicating every file

Tags: git, repository, duplicates, commit

I had a pre-existing project, which I commited to a git repository. Whenever I make changes to any of the files, the `git status` tells me that for each file I changed is untracked, and is also tracked but waiting to be added to commiting index/stage.  It's like git has an untracked version and a tracked version of the project I already commited to the repo.

If I add the untracked file and commit both, the repo updates with the tracked file, and has a duplicate file but appended with a `~`.  So I'd have a `file.txt` and `file.txt~` on the repo.

How can I get it to stop making an untracked version for files I've already added and commited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your editor is creating backup copies with `~` appended to the name, and `git` hasn't been instructed to ignore them.

Did you try creating a `.gitignore` file and adding the following pattern?

```
*~
```